# Can we convert non unicode fonts to unicode?

Tags: fonts, unicode, ascii

I have few non unicode(8 bit) hindi fonts, can be move these characters to  Unicode space so that they work for Unicode text.

Comment: [Pramukh Font Converter is a handy tool to convert the non Unicode text into Unicode text and vice versa.](http://www.vishalon.net/IndicResources/PramukhFontConverter.aspx): It supports following Hindi non Unicode to Hindi Unicode font conversion and vice versa...

Comment: This tool converts text to Unicode/non Unicode, but I want to convert font file(ttf) to Unicode.

Comment: [How to Re-encode a Truetype Font as a Unicode Font](http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/Reencoding/HowTo.html)